# How to use rendercondition visualforce on map

Tags: visualforce, map, rendered

I have a map from which i get the value in visualforce. How do I use the redner condition to check that if the falue is empty it will not render. I get the error:

Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected Boolean, received Object

See my visualforce:

```
  <apex:outputtext rendered="{!IF(!candidateFieldMap != null,true, false)}">
                    <span class="header">motivation</span><br />
                         <cxsrec:getMapValue map="{!candidateFieldMap.PersonalMotivation__c}" key="PersonalMotivation__c" /><br /> 
                    </apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ISNULL()` or `ISBLANK()` and use capital letters for `NOT()`

```
rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(candidateFieldMap))}"
```

Or avoid `NOT()` altogether:

```
rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(candidateFieldMap),false,true)}"
```

Comment: This returns: Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected Boolean, received Object

Comment: I edited my answer - try the 2nd one

Comment: no reason to use IF -- simpler: `rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(candidateFieldMap))}"` - that said testing for null collections in VF is problematic at times without controller support

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a Boolean property in Apex class to check if the map is empty, and use that for rendered tag:

```
public boolean getIsCandidateMapEmpty() {
    return candidateFieldMap.size() == 0;
}
```

Then, in vf page:

```
rendered="{!NOT(IsCandidateMapEmpty)}"
```

reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm

Comment: This returns: Unknown property 'cxsrec.cxsSmartMap.PersonalMotivation__c'

Comment: Sry, u need to check if NOT

Comment: This returns: Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected Boolean, received Object